# error building a vtk example

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, vtk

I have recently managed to install vtk-6.3 on a Kubuntu 4.13.0-37 machine. Both cmake and vtk compilation, building, and installation go with no errors on the system. In order to try something I tried to compile [this](https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/Cxx/PolyData/GradientFilter/) example. The `cmake .` build goes with no errors. Also, the `make` command has no complaints. However, I was not able to understand why it produces a shared library (not a binary file). Second, when I run the output file using `./GradientFilter` as addressed by the example, it produces an error message saying `./GradientFilter: error while loading shared libraries: libvtkIOCore-6.3.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` Although this file is available in the destinaiton installation path of vtk `/usr/local/lib`
It could be an easy question, but I am still new to this thing. Even so, vtk is not what I primarily want but I have tried something to see whether vtk works by its own.

Comment: On Stack Overflow we want problematic code to be written directly in the question post (as text), not linked. Please, add content of your `CMakeLists.txt` into the question post. You write that `make`  produces shared library, but `GradientFilter` (a file with no extension) is actually an executable, not a library.

Comment: In your case, `make` is producing an executable. But you have not linked your executable to your installed VTK library correctly. Try printing the output of `${VTK_USE_FILE}` from the `CMakeLists.txt` to see if it is pointing to a valid location for your VTK installation. Something seems wrong about your installation.